# I taking current date and i want to reveive currenttime everymessage but it coming same in textview

Tags: java, android, datetime, textview, datetime-format

I'm getting the current datetime and I want to refresh the current datetime on  every message but it is not updating in my textview. I'm making a instant messaging application like whatsapp.  I want to get the datetime with every text message but my textview shows the same datetime on every message. I think I should make a arraylist and take last datetime but this is not working.

```
datearray.add(dateFormat.format(date).toString());
tarih.setText(datearray.get(datearray.size() - 1));
```

Comment: I don't really understand your post. what do you mean "I want to use different"? do you take the current time at sending, or at recieving?
each message should have it's own timestamp, you shouldn't share one between them all, if you do that, it's pretty normal they 'll all have the same.

Comment: i receive currentdate time same for very message but every message send time different. thanks. Textview getting last currentime to every message

Comment: Post the code where you retrieve data. Are you using adapter?

Comment: data is current date time; i make that but not working datearray.add(dateFormat.format(date).toString());       tarih.setText(datearray.get(datearray.size() - 1));